# 401 Unauthorized Response On Post

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

I've been making node.js website using angular template.
But I can't create data on DB(Mongo). 
Here are code.

node routing.

```
var Property = mongoose.model('Property');
var jwt = require('express-jwt');
var auth = jwt({
  secret: 'SECRET',
  userProperty: 'payload'
});
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId; //Have also tried Schema.Types.ObjectId, mongoose.ObjectId

// Property Routing Management

router.post('/property', auth, function(req, res, next) {
  var property = new Property(req.body);
  console.log("checkpoint api");
  property.save(function(err, property) {
    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    }
    return res.json(property);
  })
});
```

AngularJS HTML

```
<form class="form-horizontal">

  <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="title">Member Name:</label>
  <div class="col-md-5">
    <input id="notific8_text" type="text" class="form-control" value="" placeholder="" ng-model="property.user">
  </div>
  <button ng-click="updateProperty()"> Submit </button>
</form>
```

AngularJS Controller.

```
angular.module('MainApp').controller('EditPropertyController', [
        '$scope',         
        's_property', 
        's_auth', 
        '$state', 
        '$location',
        function($scope, s_property, s_auth, $state, $location) {
    $scope.updateProperty = function()
    {
        var data = {
            user: $scope.property.user,            
        }
        s_property.create(data);
    };
}]);
```

and AngularJS service.

```
angular.module('MetronicApp')
  .factory('s_property', [
    '$http',
    '$window',
    's_auth',
    function($http, $window, s_auth) {
      var service = {
        all_properties: [],
        current_property: {}
      };

      service.create = function(property) {
        console.log("checkpoint service");
        return $http.post('/api/v1/property', property);
      };
    };
  ]);
```

When I input data in the input tag and click the submit button, chrome console shows like this

```
POST http://localhost:3000/property 401 (Unauthorized)
```

What is the mistake?
Cheers.

PS

this is

```js
angular.module('MainApp')
.factory('s_auth', ['$http', '$window', function($http, $window){
 var auth = {};

 auth.saveToken = function (token) {
  $window.localStorage['current-user-token'] = token;
 };

 auth.getToken = function() {
  return $window.localStorage['current-user-token'];
 };
 }
```

service

Comment: Should that not be `/api/v1/property`? Seems you have something that is messing with the route you are not telling us about.

Comment: Your backend requires a JWT yet you're not adding any `Authorization` headers in your request. Makes the "401 **Unauthorized**" response kind of obvious, don't you think?

Comment: Hello, Neil, thanks for your answer. it's my typing error. console shows POST http://localhost:3000/api/v1/property 401 (Unauthorized). Cheers.

Comment: Establishing bearer tokens usually takes a couple of authorization requests. Where are you doing that? How is `s_auth.getToken()` populated with a token?

Comment: Hi Phil, I've updated my question.

Comment: How / when are you calling `s_auth.saveToken`?

Comment: When I login s_auth.saveToken is called.

Comment: Mr, Phil, is there anyway that I can contact to you directly if you are okay? I wanna learn more from you.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are not sending the JWT token to your backend. 
TO be sending it try adding `headers { authorization: "{TOKEN}"}` in your post request